# Page is reloading when form submit usng jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I am trying to submit a form using jquery ajax. My problem is when I submitting the form its submitting but my page is reloading. I tried using `preventDefault()`. But I still couldn't figure this out.

This is the HTML for my form:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="addCategoryForm">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="new_category" name="new_category" autofocus>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control" name="parentCategoryList">
            <option value="">-- Parent Category --</option>
            <option value="">Lorem ipsum</option>
            <option value="">Lorem ipsdffum</option>
        </select>   
    </div>      
    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-default" id="addCategory">Add New Category</button>
    </div>  
</form>
```

This is how I tried it using jQuery:

```
$(document).on('click', 'button#addCategory', function (e) {    
    //e.preventDefault();       

    var data = $("form#addCategoryForm").serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "./includes/process.php",
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function() {
            window.tr.animate({'backgroundColor':'#fb6c6c'},300);
        },
        success: function (response) {

            $('#success').html(response);
            $("#success-alert").fadeTo(2000, 500).slideUp(1000, function(){
                $("#success-alert").alert('close');
            });             
        }           
    });

    //return false;

});
```

When I uncomment `e.preventDefault();` form is not sumbitting. If I comment it form is submitting but page is reloading.

Can anybody tell me whats the problem of this?

Hope somebody may help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should listen to the submit event, your elements were enclosed by a form

Try this event

```
  $('#addCategoryForm').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        //Do ajax here

  }
```

Comment: yes it seems to be working. Why it doesn't work with click event?

Comment: the form still submits because your not halting it. its the normal form behavior

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<div class="form-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="addCategory">Add New Category</button>
</div>
```

Please note that i have added `type="button"` . This is because, when no type is mentioned, by default it takes it as a submit button. And that is the reason why page reloads